# Trying to exclude featured posts from Wordpress post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Ive installed a featured post plugin "NS Featured Posts" which works quite nicely but has no known functionality for excluding those posts from another loop. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="all-news-block" class="container">
<div class="row">
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'post',
'posts_per_page'=>-1,
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_is_ns_featured_post',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="news-item-block col-md-4" role="article">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
        <a class="news-item-image-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-news-item-image'); ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <span class="news-item-date"><?php echo get_the_date('M d, Y'); ?></span>
        <a class="news-item-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display posts that have not the selected for the featured post then you need to write the meta query like this :

```
'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_is_ns_featured_post',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Since I cannot comment due to the lack of reputation, I will post this as an answer although I don't think is a final/suitable answer.

Focusing on the array you have in there:

```
    array(
        'key'     => '_is_ns_featured_post',
        'value'   => 'yes',
        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
    ),
```

I would rather change the third value (2) to this - as a regular php operator -:

```
    'compare' => '!=',
```

Also, you could change the while loop in order to count **after** the number of featured posts you got.

Comment: I wonder would it be possible to use a regular `wp_get_recent_posts` **exclude** array to target items with the key value above?